# How to write __iter__ for to iterate from leaf node back to root?

Tags: python, search, tree, iterator

I'm implementing a search algorithm (BFS) and have the following `Node` class:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, state=None, action=None, path_cost=None, parent=None):
        self._state = state
        self._action = action
        self._path_cost = path_cost
        self._parent = parent
```

My BFS solver returns the solution node (child). With this node I can then, for example, calculate the total path cost as follows (this code is part of another `Summary` class):

```
    def path_cost(self):
        self._cost = self._node.path_cost
        node = self._node.parent
        while node:
            self._cost += node.path_cost
            node = node.parent

        return self._cost
```

Is there a better way to do this by creating a custom `__iter__` method in `Node`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this generator function will work:

```
class Node:
    def __iter__(self):
        node = self
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node._parent

# elsewhere
cost = sum(n.path_cost for n in self._node)
    # ....
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. While I see how that works, my specific question is whether `__iter__` can be used to solve the problem? If not, I need to learn why not.

Comment: Updated. The `__iter__` itself can be a generator function.